# Major help needed in detailed waterfall

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, sculpting, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

There are many youtube tutorials on making a waterfall, and a lot of similar answers on this site, but none are as detailed as the one I am trying to make. I hope my question won't be marked a duplicate, because I can't find a similar answer to such a detailed scene. The reference is below:[image]

I am still a intermediate blender user, and I am not able to make anything like this. I started this project a few weeks ago, but even though I tried to sculpt such a landscape there was no luck. Nor did the greenery look good. I tried my best in using detailed smoke and water sims, but it did not work even though I tried one with resolution divisions so high (upto 600 I think) that it took 10 days to bake but with no luck. It is so detailed that I gave up on it after a few days work. I turned to this forum as a last resort. I can't even open that file because it is so heavy so I can add screenshots of my past tries. I hope that this forum is also for such circumstances. I also need help in the lighting and materials of this scene. Thanks in advance!

Comment: look at this, https://youtu.be/kQ0x0R_yHrs?t=600 it is a simple and common way to do this kind of thing, as long as it isn't really really close up

Comment: Ambitious but way to broad for this site. Recommend split it up into several tasks/questions as we do in the real world (eg. in a studio). You can sit down weeks on siming the waterfall but the sim itself has nothing to do with the vegetation or how to model a rock formation or all that other stuff in the reference. Consider that there isn't much space in the answer section and we can not write a phd into that. Scultpting the landscape is a good idea and that's how you'd approch it. Just to let you know: this is no forum, it's a Q&A site, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, thanks for informing, I will delete this one and instead ask the questions one step at a time? First I should ask a question about the terrain, then the fluid, and finally the lighting, am I right?

Comment: Yes, think about what's necessary to get there and try to ask manageable  questions, this way it's useful to future visitors too (people having the same question). BSE is some kind of knowledgebase... otherwise you can always try blenderartists.org. Sidenote: Haven't tested mantaflow extensively but I don't think that you can get such quality out of blender (for animation). Hope this helps a bit along the way.

Comment: @brockmann Thanks a lot for the information! I will try what you said.

Comment: A quick way would be to use a picture of waterfall water and make it slide on the Z axis on an Image Texture with alpha layer: https://zupimages.net/up/21/24/1b2u.gif

Comment: @moonboots That would be good for the  main waterfall, byt I won't get good details in the rest of the scene. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: well, if it's for whole scene, Blender Stack Exchange is not made for a so broad question  ;)

Comment: @moonboots Yes, so that is why I am going to ask this question in parts now.

Comment: @JBlock Thanks for the information, that and a little more information I learned will be very helpful.